# I can't open a HTML Customized page using Python for some reason

Tags: python, html, operating-system, converters

Here is my code so far:

```
import os

print("The Arkeyan Text to HTML Converter\n\n")

w = 1

while w == 1:
   var1 = input("\n\nWhat would you like the title of your page to be? ")
   var2 = input("\nCool! Okay, now what is the text you want inside the body? ")
   align = input("\nHow would you like this to be aligned? (center, right or left) ")
   background = input("\nFinally, what background colour would you like? (It has to be in RGB format). Press 9 for more info.")

   if background == "9":
      background = input("\nGo to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp to get a colour value and enter it in here: ")
      print("\n\nAll done! Here is your personalised code:\n\n")
      code = print("<!Doctype html>\n\
      <html>\n\
      <head>\n\
            <title>",var1,"</title>\n\
      </head>\n\n\n\
      <body bgcolor=\"",background,"\">\n\
      <div align=\"",align,"\">\n\
      <h1>",var1,"</h1><br>\n\
      <p>",var2,"</p>\n\
      </div>\n\
      </body>\n\
      </html>")

      my_file = open("C:\output.html", "w")

      my_file.write(str(code))

      my_file.close()

      os.system("C:\\output.html")

      x = input("\n\nThank you for using this HTML convert tool. Would you like to generate another code? ")
      if x == "yes":
         print("\n\n==========UNDERGOING LOOP PROCESS==========\n")
      elif x == "no":
         print("\n\n==========BREAKING THE LOOP==========\n")
         w = 2
      else:
         print("I don't understand you. Self-destruct sequence initaiated...")
         exit()

   else:

      print("\n\nAll done! Here is your personalised code:\n\n")
      code = print("<!Doctype html>\n\
      <html>\n\
      <head>\n\
            <title>",var1,"</title>\n\
      </head>\n\n\n\
      <body bgcolor=\"",background,"\">\n\
      <div align=\"",align,"\">\n\
      <h1>",var1,"</h1><br>\n\
      <p>",var2,"</p>\n\
      </div>\n\
      </body>\n\
      </html>")

      my_file = open("C:\output.html", "w")

      my_file.write(str(code))

      my_file.close()

      os.system("C:\\output.html")

      x = input("\n\nThank you for using this HTML convert tool. Would you like to generate another code? ")
      if x == "yes":
         print("\n\n==========UNDERGOING LOOP PROCESS==========\n")
      elif x == "no":
         print("\n\n==========BREAKING THE LOOP==========\n")
         w = 2
      else:
         print("I don't understand you. Self-destruct sequence initaiated...")
         exit()
```

The HTML Page is opening up fine, but it says 'None'! Why is that? I have checked it several times, and can't seem to resolve the issue. Can you help me? P.S. I need my error fixed quite quickly; I have to submit it soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning

```
print
```

to "code" (print returns None).

Comment: so i remove the print element?

Comment: In: 
    code = print("<!Doctype html>\n\ ...

remove "code ="

Answer (score 1):

`print` does not return anything, so `code = print(...)` means that `code` will always be `None`.

Remove the call to `print` if you want `code` to be a string.  You will also need to use a different method to format your string.  Basic `+` concatenation works, or (better) use string formatting:

```
'this is a {} string'.format('formatted')
#this is a formatted string
```

read more in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).